# knitr syntax highlighting in .Rnw files (LaTeX)

Tags: r, latex, syntax-highlighting, knitr

I am using .Rnw files to produce a report with LaTeX and knitr.

My `knitr_setup` looks as follows:

```
<<knitr_setup, echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(highlight = TRUE, cache = TRUE, eval = FALSE, size = "small")
options(width = 60)
opts_knit$set(out.format = "latex")
@
<<theme, cache=FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
thm = knit_theme$get("olive")
knit_theme$set(thm)
@
```

I tested several syntax highlighting themes. Previews are provided [here](https://rclickhandbuch.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/knitrthemesoverview.pdf).
However, changing the themes in `knit_theme$get()` only results in a different background (for some) in the final pdf. Syntax highlighting stays with the default colors.

R-Version: 3.3.1
RStudio Version: 0.99.1280 (Preview)
knitr-Version: 1.13

What is wrong in my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem:** You have a document with several calls to `knit_theme$set()` and expect syntax highlighting to change accordingly, on a per-chunk basis.

> Syntax highlighting stays with the default colors.

Each call to `knit_theme$set()` supersedes the previous call. This is because the colors for syntax highlighting are defined just once, in the LaTeX preamble (e.g. `\newcommand{\hlnum}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.529,0.875,0.443}{#1}}`).

> However, changing the themes in knit_theme$get() only results in a different background (for some) in the final pdf.

Unlike highlighting of keywords, the background color is defined for each chunk (look for `\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.961, 0.961, 0.961}`). (Exception: Chunks with `results  = "asis"`.)

**The solution (concept):**
Using `\renewcommand`, the syntax highlighting commands can be "updated" mid-document. We can therefore set a new theme, extract its syntax highlighting definitions, replace `newcommand` by `renewcommand` and write the definitions to the document. All subsequent chunks will use the new theme.
At the end of the document, restore the default theme; otherwise, all chunks *before* the first change of theme will use the *last* theme set.

**Implementation:**

```
setThemeInline <- function(theme) {
  knit_theme$set(knit_theme$get(theme))
  header <- opts_knit$get("header")["highlight"]
  header <- gsub(pattern = "newcommand",
                 replacement = "renewcommand",
                 x = header)
  cat(header)
}
```

**Usage:**

Note that `setThemeInline` must be called in an `asis` chunk. Don't forget to restore the theme (see last chunk). Only chunks *after* the chunk where `setThemeInline` was called will be affected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<setup>>=
library(knitr)

setThemeInline <- function(theme) {
  knit_theme$set(knit_theme$get(theme))
  header <- opts_knit$get("header")["highlight"]
  header <- gsub(pattern = "newcommand",
                 replacement = "renewcommand",
                 x = header)
  cat(header)

  # for chunks with results = "asis"
  shadecolor <- col2rgb(opts_chunk$get("background")) / 255
  cat(sprintf("\\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{%s, %s, %s}",
              shadecolor[1, 1], shadecolor[2, 1], shadecolor[3, 1]))
}

@


<<theme, results='asis'>>=
setThemeInline("denim")
@

<<>>=
getAnswer <- function(question) {
  if (missing(question)) {
    stop("Ask something!")
  }
  return(42)
}
@

<<results='asis'>>=
setThemeInline("vampire")
@

<<>>=
getAnswer <- function(question) {
  if (missing(question)) {
    stop("Ask something!")
  }
  return(42)
}
@

<<restore>>=
knit_theme$set(knit_theme$get("default"))
@

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: Sometimes, I think there must be a "10 minute solution". And only after 2 hours I realize that I was wrong …